# Разница между разными видами объявлений массивов

Tags: массивы, функции, указатели, const

Правильно ли я понимаю, что:

```
// f - массив указателей на функции a, b и c.
// Содержимое массива можно менять.
void (*f[])(void) = {a, b, c};

// Формально, f - это указатель на указатель на функцию.
// В данный момент f указывает на массив, который содержит
// указатели на функции.
// Содержимое массива, на который указывает f, менять нельзя,
// т.к. массив скорее всего располагается в области памяти только для чтения,
// как и строковые литералы.
// Однако, в f можно записать адрес другого массива или одиночного
// указателя на функцию.
void (**f)(void) = {a, b, c};

// Формально, содержимое массива f менять нельзя, как
// и в предыдущем случае.
// Однако, это и предыдущее определения все же формально отличаются.
// Данное определение создает массив, который содержит константные указатели,
// но этот массив совсем не обязательно располагается в области памяти
// только для чтения, const скорее всего относится ко времени компиляции.
void (*const f[])(void) = {a, b, c};

// *f[] - f является именем массива указателей, поэтому мы не можем 
// отвязать это имя от массива, то есть, мы не можем записать в f адрес
// (как это правильно называется?).

// **f - f является именем указателя, поэтому мы можем присвоить 
// указателю с именем f другой адрес.
```